# Flutter app keeps disconnecting from firestore after brief time

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on an application that causes devices connected to firestore to vibrate on cue. Currently it works fine, but after ~5+ minutes of a connected device/app being put to sleep, there is no response. Currently I have it so connected devices are given a bool field which has a listener to vibrate the device when the bool is true. I was thinking of sending a push notification to try and force the device to vibrate, but that's if there's no solution. Is there anyway to force the device to remain listening for firestore changes for an extended period of time? (listening in the background)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior and not anything Firebase/Firestore controls. To conserve battery life, Android closes connections from applications if they haven't been actively used in a while.

For this reason you can't expect to keep receiving updates from Firestore (or any other such mechanism) if the app is backgrounded or if the phone is put to sleep.

The common solution for this is indeed to (also) send updates through FCM, which is treated differently by Android's power management feature.

Comment: Okay I'll look into it. FCM is also how push notifications are sent right? Hopefully I can customize the duration of the vibration, but no biggie if not. Thanks for the answer.